# Comment dit-on poliment le contraire de « tu peux me tutoyer » ?

Tags: politesse, tutoiement

[Cette question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2406/832) m'a fait penser : y a-t-il une phrase qui a le sens de *ne me tutoie pas, s'il te plaît* mais qui soit peu plus polie ? Si j'appelle quelqu'un *tu* et qu'il n'aprecie pas, qu'est-ce qu'il peut faire pour me dire ?

Comment: "Ne me tutoie pas, s'il te plaît" serait non seulement assez impoli, mais complètement illogique (ou volontairement méprisant) avec de rares exceptions (par ex. un professeur s'adressant à un élève). "Ne me tutoyez pas, s'il vous plaît" serait déjà plus adapté (mais pas plus indiqué).

Comment: @Dave: C'était volontairement ridicule. :P

Comment: « Pouvez-vous me vouvoyer s'il vous plait ? » est bon, non ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

« Je serais plus à l'aise si l'on se vouvoyait » ?

Comment: J'aime beaucoup cette façon de l'exprimer. Elle n'implique aucune hauteur.

Comment: Encore mieux que M'vy!

Comment: Et implique que c'est le locuteur qui a une difficulte ("je serais plus a l'aise..."), plutot que de rabaisser autrui. Superbe.

Answer (score 20):

La politesse absolue sera de ne rien dire, et de continuer à vouvoyer l'autre avec insistance.

Il est donc question de degré de malpolitesse...

Au plus bas degré, je dirais : « vous avez quelque chose contre le vouvoiement ? », impliquant que le tutoiement n'est pas préféré.

En y pensant, c'est surtout le ton avec lequel c'est dit, plus que les mots, qui feront la différence entre une attaque et une prise de distance sans animosité. La phrase que j'ai proposée peut tout aussi bien être dite avec agressivité...

(Du côté humoristique, mais plus pour la blague que pour une utilisation concrète, on peut aussi rétorquer : « Je ne laisse me tutoyer que les femmes avec qui j'ai couché et les hommes avec qui j'ai mangé 50kg de sel ». À adapter pour une version féminine...)

Comment: Il ne me souvient pas vous avoir vu à côté de moi lorsque, jadis, j'accompagnais quelques porcidés pour éviter qu'ils ne s'égarassent.

Comment: Merci ! Je pensait qu'il vaut mieux de ne rien dire, mais un autre opinion est toujours utile.

Comment: @UnFrancophone *Suidés* :)

Comment: @Un francophone : La version de *Cyrano de Bergerac* est assez bien trouvée (et en alexandrins, évidemment) : « Si tu ?... Tu ?... Qu’est-ce donc qu’ensemble nous gardâmes ? » (bizarrement, j'avais gardé en mémoire « Tu ? tu ? qu'est-ce donc qu'ensemble nous élevâmes ? » mais c'est pas ça)

Answer (score 15):

> Je préfère que l'on continue de se vouvoyer.

Est une formule qui n'est pas agressive, ne force pas l'interlocuteur et marque toujours le même niveau de respect.

Comment: Je dirais la même chose, le fait de ramener le problème à soi-même est un bon moyen d'éviter l'affront.

Comment: Bizarrement je mettrais plutôt "continue à".

Comment: +1 pour Joubarc, mais je trouve quand même que la formule force la main à/de l'interlocuteur.

Answer (score 2):

*Cher Monsieur, je vous prie de me vouvoyer. [Nous n’avons pas gardé les cochons ensemble](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_gard%C3%A9_les_cochons_ensemble)!*

Comment: C'est franc et extrêmement direct, mais je doute que ce soit ce que  Jon Purdy demande.

Answer (score 1):

Version bovidés :

> On s'est pas connus aux culs des vaches à ce que je sache !

et la banlieue de Paris a sa propre version simple et tonique que vous pouvez *châtier* :

> D'où c'est qu'on se tutoie ?

Plus sérieusement, le tutoiement est souvent utilisé par les non francophones, tout simplement parce qu'il simplifie la conjugaison, la forme du verbe à la première personne du singulier et à la deuxième personne du singulier est souvent la même, alors qu'en utilisant « vous », la forme du verbe est différente, mais les français restent très sensibles au tutoiement, même sans connaissance de l'histoire du pays et en particulier de la révolution, dans leur culture le « tu » reste le symbole de l'infériorité hiérarchique et la frontière entre vie publique et vie privée. La révolution de 1789 a tenté de rendre l'usage du « tu » systématique pour abolir la hiérarchisation de la société. La société restant hiérarchisée, l'usage du « tu » rappelle la féodalité quand le noble tutoyait le paysan, parce qu'il était son supérieur et propriétaire. Apprendre la forme du verbe à la deuxième personne du pluriel est un effort supplémentaire pour les non francophones, mais cet effort est nécessaire pour avoir de bonnes relations avec les français.

Answer (score 1):

Vous permettez qu'on se vouvoie ?

Answer (score 0):

L'histoire de la facilité pour les étrangers ne tient pas. Ils peuvent avoir à s'adresser à deux ou plusieurs personnes. On ne tutoie jamais un groupe.

Comment: En quoi cela répond-il à la question ?